# Removing gray box on first page of template

Tags: graphics, templates

I'm using the Oxford University Press template in Overleaf and there's a gray box on the first page that I can't seem to eliminate. Here's a template using that style where you can see the gray box next to the logo: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/pnas-nexus/wfqcdvjdrqmz

Where in the file is that gray box defined? How can I eliminate or replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gray box appears (hardcoded) 9 times in the class, according to the choices of modern, contemporary, or traditional; and large, medium or small.

The patch will replace the gray color with white while keeping the space.

[image: a]

Add this code after `\documentclass{...`

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\color{black!20}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{\color{white}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\color{black!20}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{\color{white}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\color{black!20}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{\color{white}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\color{black!20}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{\color{white}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\color{black!20}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{\color{white}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\color{black!20}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{\color{white}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\color{black!20}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{\color{white}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\color{black!20}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{\color{white}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\color{black!20}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{\color{white}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Using `regexpatch` it is possible to have a more compact code.

`\xpatchcmd*` will replace all occurrences of the color of the boxes.

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\@maketitle}{\color{black!20}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{\color{white}\rule{45pt}{55pt}}{}{}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you so much!